# Custom media queries with either bootstrap or angular material

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, media-queries

We have a application developed using Angular with Material and bootstrap. So my concern is in some pages the content is not mobile friendly i.e not responsive. Not responsive with material table data, some graphical data like chartjs data etc.

So to achieve complete responsive can we write custom media queries with both these CSS libraries? Or is it going to have some performance issues with the site loading? Means performance will effect if i use media queries? Can anyone enlighten on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom media queries in component level css files for the specific component, that will not affect the performance of your application.

Comment: Thanks Ankit for your quick response.